# sql server to oracle query conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, oracle11g

I need to convert  SQL Server Query into Oracle , can somebody help

```
WITH e AS
(
     SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER
         (
             PARTITION BY fname
             ORDER BY dojoin DESC
         ) AS Recency
     FROM Dept 
    WHERE deptno= 55
)
SELECT *
FROM e
WHERE Recency = 1 
ORDER BY fname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle requires that you prefix the asterisk if there are additional columns in the `select` clause:

```
WITH e AS
(
     SELECT Dept.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER
         (
             PARTITION BY fname
             ORDER BY dojoin DESC
         ) AS Recency
     FROM Dept where deptno= 55
)
SELECT *
FROM e
WHERE Recency = 1 
order by fname
```